# How to get a value from one view controller to another view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

**//viewcontrollerA.h**

```
@class viewA;
@protocol viewADelegate<NSObject>
- (void)emailidgetmethod:(NSString *)string;

@end

@interface Login : UIViewController
{

}
@property (nonatomic,assign) id <viewADelegate> delegate;
@end
```

**//viewcontrollerA.m**

```
#import "viewcontrollerA.h"
 @synthesize delegate;

 - (void)viewDidLoad 
  {
   [self.delegate emailidgetmethod:@"myString"];
  }
```

**//viewcontrollerB.h**

```
  #import "viewcontrollerA.h"
  @interface viewcontrollerB : UIViewController<viewADelegate>
  @end
```

**//viewcontrollerB.m**
        #import "viewcontrollerB.h"

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad 
   {
       viewcontrollerA *viewA= [[viewcontrollerA alloc]init];
       [viewA setDelegate:self];
   }

 - (void)emailidgetmethod:(NSString *)string
   {
       NSLog(@"Delegatehomemethod %@",string); // This is not calling.
   }
```

Comment: what do you want you want to send string from one view controller to another?

Comment: i want to access the view controllerA from view controllerB without getinto the view controllerA.

Comment: you can save valu in User Default & then get it from other View Controller.

Comment: @Deepakravi, viewController A is then in Navigation Array or not ?

Comment: viewControllerA is not a Navigation Array. i want to access the data in view controllerA data without pushing viewcontrollerA screen.

Answer (score -1):

Method doesn't calling because viewDidLoad method of viewControllerA doesn't calling. You should add viewControllerA as child to viewControllerB and add view of viewContollerA as subview of viewControllerB's view

Answer (score -1):

I think, your `ViewControllerA` is loading first and then you navigate to `ViewControllerB` Controllers. If that is your case, your delegate function will not call because as you can see, when your `ViewControllerA` is loaded and `viewDidLoad` is called, your `delegate` is nil so it will not able to call function.

So you need to load `ViewControllerB` first and navigate to `ViewControllerA`

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You are calling an instance method which is declared in ViewControllerA in another ViewController. This won't be called because you can only access that method within ViewControllerA. You can change the -(void) to +(void), to make it a class method. Then in your ViewControllerB, create an instance of ViewControllerA`ViewControllerA *VCA = [[ViewControllerA alloc] init];`
Then you can access this method within ViewControllerA.`[VCA methodName];`